# How to resolve ValueError: Columns must be same length as key?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a huge dataset  (104259 rows) and somewhere in the column `game`, there are one or more values that have more than one `" - "` delimeters which I am trying to split these columns by.

My example dataframe is:

```
df:
+-----+--------------+----------------+-------------+--------+---------------------------------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+------------------------------+
|     |   Unnamed: 0 |   Unnamed: 0.1 | date        | time   | game                                  | score    | home_odds   | draw_odds   | away_odds   | country   | league                       |
+=====+==============+================+=============+========+=======================================+==========+=============+=============+=============+===========+==============================+
|   0 |            0 |              0 | nan         | 15:30  | Iliria Kruja - Cerrik                 | 0:3      | -           | -           | -           | Albania   | First Division               |
+-----+--------------+----------------+-------------+--------+---------------------------------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+------------------------------+
|   1 |            1 |              1 | 25 Jul 2020 | 15:30  | Elbasani - Devolli                    | 3:1      | -           | -           | -           | Albania   | First Division               |
+-----+--------------+----------------+-------------+--------+---------------------------------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+------------------------------+
|   2 |            2 |              2 | 11 Jul 2020 | 15:30  | Beselidhja Lezha - Kastrioti          | 2:0      | 1.46        | 3.80        | 6.40        | Albania   | First Division               |
+-----+--------------+----------------+-------------+--------+---------------------------------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+------------------------------+
|   3 |            3 |              3 | 05 Jul 2020 | 15:30  | Lushnja - Apolonia Fier               | 1:2      | 2.39        | 3.56        | 2.44        | Albania   | First Division               |
+-----+--------------+----------------+-------------+--------+---------------------------------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+------------------------------+
```

When I run this part of the code:

```
df[['home_team', 'away_team']] = df['game'].str.split(' - ', expand=True)
```

I am getting this error:

```
        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/harsh/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2021.1/scratches/scratch_37.py", line 22, in <module>
    df[['home_team', 'away_team']] = df['game'].str.split(' - ', expand=True)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3160, in __setitem__
    self._setitem_array(key, value)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3189, in _setitem_array
    raise ValueError("Columns must be same length as key")
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

While I doubt that there are one or more rows where `str.split` is encountering it more than once however, I am not sure which rows.

Now, I have a choice of:

1. If there are lesser rows with this kind of data (less than 10), I can safely opt to drop them or
2. If there are more than 10 rows, I can split them by the first time this delimiter is encountered.

I am just not sure how to do this code-wise.

How can I inspect and tackle this issue?

Comment: which version of pandas we you using?

Comment: @quest I am using pandas v 1.2.3

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: @furas Sure. I should had known this. Have updated the question. Thanks

Comment: @PyNoob_N, are you sure if column `game` has `-`  across all the rows?

Comment: @KarnKumar Yes, there is atleast one `-` accross all rows. What I suspect is that there are more than one of those which is the issue. I would like to inspect however dont really know how.

Answer (score 2):

Probably some of your rows have more than a single `" - "` string. If you are pretty sure about structure and you want to split by the first time the delimiter is encountered use the following the `n` parameter, as following:

```
df['game'].str.split(' - ', expand=True, n=1)
```

Documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html).

Comment: Thanks. However, is tehre any way I can inspect my data where this is occuring?

Comment: It could probably be achieved using pd.Series.str.count method in order to filter your dataframe. Something like that:

df.loc[lambda x: x['game'].str.count(' - ') != 1]